# in_category in index.php

Tags: categories

I am trying to separate categories because I am working on a theme that will have many different sections on the front page. It makes sense to use categories for these sections. Right now, I have three sections set up with posts in 3 different categories. I have a blog, about and team category. Each category has specific html to it. So in the main loop, I am trying to check for which category is being displayed. I thought I could do something like this..

```
 if has post
 while has post, the post
 if in_cateogory('blog')
   get post content
 endif
 endwhile
 endif
```

When I do that, I don't get any posts showing on the front page. index.php does not get the blog section. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me. I tied in a child theme of TwentyTwelve. Just copy and replace your `index.php` with the following and let me know (And don't forget to change the category slug as per your database):

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) :
   while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      if(in_category('aciform'))
        { echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>'; }
      else if(in_category('blogroll'))
        { echo '<h2> K-'. get_the_title() .'</h2>'; }
      else
        { echo "<div>bla bla</div>"; }
   endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: I used the default twenty fourteen theme as a test. I added the conditional for in_category for the blog category. The theme shows 2 pages. The 1st page is blank but page 2 does show the 3 blog posts. Why?

Comment: I found that using in_category on the index page displays the blog posts, but it put them on page two. so it's acting like all the other posts are still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `the_posts` filter and `usort` to sort the posts as needed. `the_posts` filter is unfortunately not documented

You can try something like this

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts, $q ) {
    if( $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_home() ) {
        usort( $posts, function( $a, $b ){
             return strcasecmp( 
                get_the_category( $a->ID )[0]->name, 
                get_the_category( $b->ID )[0]->name 
            );
        });
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

**EDIT**

You can also run the loop and just display one category, rewind the loop, rerun it again and show the next category and so on

```
// main loop
if (have_posts()) { 
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post();

        if( in_category( 'a' ) ) {
            //display category 'a' posts
        }
    }

    // rewind
    rewind_posts();

    // new loop
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post();

        if( in_category( 'b' ) ) {
            //display category 'b' posts
        }
    }
}
```